# Get Index value of AddressBook?

Tags: ios, addressbook

How can I get the index of the addressbook when we know the `ABRecordRef` and address book?

I am using:

```
ABRecordRef ref= CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(AddressBookPeople, index);
```

to get the record reference at a given index.

Similarly, how do I get the index of the record when the `ABRecordRef` value is known?

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` has a method:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

that returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a given object.

`CFArray` is toll-free bridged with `NSArray`. So I think this should work,

```
int index = [(NSArray *)AddressBookPeople indexOfObject:ref];
```

**EDIT:::**

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
  CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
  ABRecordRef ref= CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, 4);
  NSUInteger i = [(__bridge NSArray *)people indexOfObject:(__bridge id)(ref)];
```

This returned me right index.

Comment: here AddressBookPeople is CFArrayRef, This doesn't have indexOfObject method

Comment: Thats why I said that CFArrayRef is tollfree bridged with NSArray so it should work. You may need to typecast though. See my edit.

Comment: No its returned 20000+ record index 600 records only available

Comment: people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    
    NSArray *tempPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)(AddressBookPeople);
    
    NSUInteger i = [tempPeople indexOfObject:(__bridge id)(ref)];

Comment: So I got curious and tried it my self. See my edit. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also more properly use:

```
CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue
```